# Calling a batch file to call multiple files while draggining a picture inside

Tags: windows, batch-file, imagemagick

I made a batch file to call other batch files.

```
call ImageConvert610x.bat
call ImageConvert300x.bat
call ImageConvert270x.bat
call ImageConvert200x.bat
call ImageConvert120x.bat
call ImageConvert80x.bat
call ImageConvert50x.bat
```

Now when I drag a pic in these batch files separately, it works fine. When I drag it over this batch file, I get an error and no pics are made.

Here is what the inside one of the batches look like.

```
convert "%1" -thumbnail 610x -unsharp 1.5x1.2+1.0+0.10 "%~p1resizedxLarge_%~n1.jpg"
```

I want to know how to loop through each call and make a file for each batch I am calling when I drag a photo onto the first batch so I dont have to drag a photo onto all these files separately.

Comment: I recommend to use `"%~1"` rather than `"%1"` to avoid double-double-quotes...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix all the calls like this:

```
call ImageConvert610x.bat %*
call ImageConvert300x.bat %*
...
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is in relation to your other thread this method will probably be quicker as it only reads in the original file once:

```
convert "%1" ( -clone 0 -thumbnail x480 -write 480_wide.jpg +delete )^
( -clone 0 -thumbnail x250 -write 250_wide.jpg +delete )^
( -clone 0 -thumbnail x100 -write 100_wide.jpg +delete )null:
```